# how to hide category name in joomla?

Tags: joomla, categories

I'm working on a website based on joomla and I have to delete or hide the category under the slider, but can't figure how. I find it funny it appears here http://ozonoterapie.geromaslan.ro/index.php/2-uncategorised/4-cum-este-administrata-ozonoterapia and on another page, but on the others no.
Can you please help me fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Check this: http://www.publishyourarticles.org/joomla/general-question/best-way-to-hide-category-title-for-any-page-in-joomla.html

Hope it works for you

Comment: I tried the options there, but they are for joomla 1.5 and I'm using 1.7 and they wouldn't work.